# Use a PC as a one client router/switch

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, routing, nat, rj-45

I have a laptop running win7 , with two network cards wifi and normal wired (RJ45). I normally use the wifi for internet connectivity (Via a personal router). I have a raspberry pi, also with a rj45 ethernet connection, and I'd like to  connect it to the laptop so it can also have internet connectivity. is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Windows Internet Connection Sharing will let you share the Wifi-available Internet connection out of the laptop's Ethernet.

The [Microsoft article](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/Using-ICS-Internet-Connection-Sharing) on it is pretty straight forward.  The connection you want to share will be the Wifi, obviously.  Make sure your Raspberry Pi is set to get an IP via DHCP (ICS hands out 192.168.1.X/255.255.255.0 IP's).

You can even put a switch between your laptop's Ethernet and Rapsberry Pi if you want multiple devices to share the laptop's Internet connection.